# How to stream audio with VLC via Bash in Debian without GUI?

Tags: bash, audio, debian, streaming, vlc

I'm struggeling very hard at the moment. Does anyone know how to stream audio via commandline with vlc? I'm using an Debian without GUI. My target is my system (localhost) I've been looking for weeks now.

```
vlc /data/sound.mp3 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=localhost:8080}'
```

this is what I have. Can anyone help me?

Thank you, Granit

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code can help you.

```
vlc -vvv /data/sound.mp3 --sout '#rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=8080,sdp=sap}'
```

Be sure it is in the vlc class.

Comment: I still get a error which says: "stream chain faild"